# Deployment of Openbravo in GoDaddy Server

Tags: java, linux, erp, openbravo

I have successfully installed Openbravo ERP 3.0 with PostgreSQL in local linux system. But I want to deploy this ERP in GoDaddy server.

Can anyone suggest me the procedure to migrate from local server to hosting server with PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Backup postgres ,Openbravo sources and tomcat context.

2.Restore postgres DB and  Openbravo sources in server.

3.Configure Openbravo.properties in server.

4.Execute  "ant update.database trl.lib wad.lib compile.complete.deploy"